# Windows 8 Metro/Modern-UI Apps won't start - Keeps losing ALL_APPLICATION_PACKAGES permissions on ‪C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Packages

Tags: windows-8, modern-ui

My Windows 8 Metro apps won't start. They flip the screen, show an icon, then go back to the new start menu. I went to Store and updated everything. I installed latest Windows update (from desktop). Simple things like Weather won't start.

I found this in the event viewer > Administrative Events:

> App  crashed with an unhandled Javascript exception. App details are as follows: Display Name:, AppUserModelId:  Package Identity: PID:<10732>. The details of the JavaScript exception are as follows Exception Name:, Description:, Source File Name:, Source Line Number:<19>, Source Column Number:<1>, and Stack Trace: ms-appx://microsoft.bingweather/js/settingsManager.js:19:1           Anonymous function()

```
       ms-appx://microsoft.bingweather/js/settingsManager.js:9:1           Anonymous function()
       ms-appx://microsoft.bingweather/js/settingsManager.js:6:2           Global code
```

.

Adding modify permissions to ‪C:\Users\Chloe\AppData\Local\Packages for user ALL_APPLICATION_PACKAGES fixes it, but I've done this before and it appears to keep losing that permission on that folder.

**How can I prevent ALL_APPLICATION_PACKAGES permissions from being lost on AppData\Local\Packages?**

Comment: What is your resolution set at? Did they ever work?

Comment: If you have to modify the permissions of that folder something isn't right with the system image itself.